# Protractor install fail

Tags: node.js, npm, jasmine, protractor

Trying to install last version of protractor (4.0.10) with node v4.6.0 install failing.

I am getting this error:

```
bower@1.7.9 C:\Users\mallain\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @types/jasmine
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 '@types/jasmine' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'protractor'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mallain\workspace\angular-catalogue-module\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Are you using a custom npm registry? It's trying to find types for jamine and coming up empty.

Comment: Actually I was, and my issue came from a bad configuration of this registry. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating node and npm to the latest versions. @types is a fairly recent convention.

Answer (score -1):

That was a registry issue in my company.

Changing the project registry to a valid one fixed this ! :)